# Does it follow from Urysohn's lemma?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $U$ be a non-empty open set of $X$ with non-empty complement. Can I find a continuous function $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$f(x)=1$ for $x\in X\setminus U$

and

$f(x)<1$ for all $x\in U$?

This is clear if $U$ is an open interval in $X=[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ but how about the general case?

Comment: I think there is a typo: maybe it should be $f(x) < 1$ for all $x \in U$.

Comment: For continous $f$ with $f<0$ on U follows $f \leq 0$ on $\overline U$, which contradicts $f=1$ on $X \setminus U$. Hence there does not exist $f$ with the required properties.

Comment: As @jowehler remarks, there must be some... room between the zero region and the "one" region. If the two regions share the boundary, no continuous function can exist with the prescribed property.

Comment: Sure, of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is equivalent to the property of being a [perfectly normal space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space), assuming $X$ is compact. To see this, suppose that $X$ satisfies:

> For every nonempty open set $U$ with nonempty complement, there is a continuous function $f:X\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=1$ for $x\in X\setminus U$ and $f(x)<1$ for $x\in U$.

(Note that I took the liberty of correcting the typo pointed out in the comments.) The property of being perfectly normal gives for any two closed disjoint $F,G$ a function $X\to\Bbb R$ such that the preimages of $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are $F$ and $G$ respectively. Obviously this implies your one-sided property, so let's show the converse.

Let $F,G$ be given, and get functions $f,g$ satisfying $f^{-1}(\{1\})=F$ and $g^{-1}(\{1\})=G$, and define $m_1=\sup_{x\in G}f(x)$ and $m_2=\sup_{x\in F}g(x)$. Since $G$ is compact, $f$ achieves its supremum on $G$ at some point $x\in G$, so $m_1=f(x)<1$. Similarly, $m_2<1$. Then we can define:

$$h(x)=\frac12-\frac12\max\left(0,\frac{f(x)-m_1}{1-m_1}\right)+\frac12\max\left(0,\frac{g(x)-m_2}{1-m_2}\right).$$

Then when $x\in F$, the second term is $\max\left(0,\frac{1-m_1}{1-m_1}\right)=1$ and in the second term $g(x)\le m_2$, so $\frac{g(x)-m_2}{1-m_2}\le 0$ and $\max\left(0,\frac{g(x)-m_2}{1-m_2}\right)=0$, so $h(x)=0$. Similarly, for $x\in G, h(x)=1$. And for $x\notin F\cup G$, we have $f(x)<1\to 0\le\max\left(0,\frac{f(x)-m_1}{1-m_1}\right)<1$ and similarly for $g$ so that $h(x)<\frac12-0+\frac12=1$ and $h(x)>\frac12-\frac12+0=0$, so $h(x)$ has preimages of $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ exactly at $F$ and $G$.

Being just Hausdorff isn't nearly strong enough to ensure this.